# Scrape content inside a form - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape pages like [this](http://www.bendonlingerie.com.au/pleasure-state-d-arcy-delatour-soft-cup-bra-jester-red-p21-2346w) using BeautifulSoup and Python 3.5. Specifically, I am interested in the number of sizes. In this specific page the number of sizes is 3 (S,M,L). This information can be found inside a form in the html code.

The code that I have tried is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.bendonlingerie.com.au/pleasure-state-d-arcy-delatour-soft-cup-bra-jester-red-p21-2346w')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
right = soup.find("div", class_="product-shop")
sizes = right.find("div", id="sizes")
sizes = sizes.find("ul", class_="button-size-list combo-list")
sizes = sizes.find_all("li")
nu_of_sizes = len(sizes)
print(nu_of_sizes)
```

This code prints '0'. The correct print should be '3', since there are 3 sizes(S,M,L). I don't want to use selenium or such packages. Is there a way to 'catch' this data using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: is this link SFW? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully inspect the page source, you'll notice that the data you're interested in is in `json` format (right click the page, View Page Source, and search for `productJson`). So, you can check where it starts and where it ends, and deserialize that slice to a Python object using `json.loads()`:

```
import requests
import json

page = requests.get('http://www.bendonlingerie.com.au/pleasure-state-d-arcy-delatour-soft-cup-bra-jester-red-p21-2346w')
content = page.text

start = content.find('productJson') + 13
end = content.find('function comboListClick') - 2

data = json.loads(content[start:end])

sizes = data['attributes']['172']['options']

print(len(sizes))
```

output:

```
3
```

Comment: Thank you @mentalita . How can I check where it starts and where it ends?

Comment: @nesi: well, you'd have to manually inspect the page source to find that out.